# do we need to one hot encode or label encode target column while training machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, one-hot-encoding

Dataset having columns- 
target column-- fruit name(data- mango,orange,apple),
features column --  size(numeric),color(red,green,yellow),weight(numeric)

I have did one hot encoding on the color column and prepare the features, with every column is having the numeric values.

I want to use the classification model for the prediction.

If I am having a target column on which I have to do the prediction, is consist of categorical data(ex-apple,orange,mango), so If I want to use the logistic regression model which is a classification based model, do I need to one hot encoding or label encode the target column also, as we do for the features column(name-color).

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

No, it will work since logistic regression returns the probability of Y = y given your input X.

Comment: actually I am asking for all the classification models....because when I use these models for training the prediction always comes with label indexing not the actual name. suppose the prediction is "orange" then the output will be 2, or prediction is "apple" then the output will be 1 and so on. How to handle this type of scenario because my models won't accept the string column, it has to converted into numerical format before passing it to any machine learning algorithms.

Comment: I suggest you to convert everything to numerical data, and then you can use a dictionary to decode your output